# similar to SELECT * in sql but with only a row

Tags: sql

When we do `SELECT * FROM table` we get all records in a table, If I want to get only a row but do not know the number of columns

like

```
id   att1  att2  att3.... attx
-------------------------------
1     45     5      3        7
```

How do I do a select statement that returns all columns?
I know I must use

```
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
```

and a Where clause:  `WHERE id = 1`

but again I do not know the number of columns...

Comment: What database engine? MySQl, MSSQL, Innodb, ...? (I assume MSSQL?)

Comment: Can't you just SELECT * from INFORMAT...?

Comment: Searching SO for `[sql] rows as columns` gives numerous results, did you try? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+rows+as+columns

Comment: I don't think I understand you question but can you not just use `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table` or `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1` depending on your dbms.

Comment: can i insert the result into a table, and make the id be the ORDINAL of each  column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a where clause to the end of the @sql statement to limit your selection to the rows you want:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)

select @cols = coalesce(@cols + ', ' + column_name, column_name)
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = 'select ' + @cols + ' from myTable where Id = 1'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Excuse me @Derek: can I insert the result into a table, and make the id be the ORDINAL of each column?, so I would get a new table with the column ordinal as its id and the value the column value?

Answer (score 1):

The `*` means that you want all columns, not all "records".

```
select *
from YourTable
where ID = 1
```

Comment: A database table has **rows** - not records - but otherwise, you're correct :-)

Comment: @marc_s - Can't argue with that :). I just picked the word that OP used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to know the number of columns if you are interesting in pulling out the details of all. Just give the `where` condition with `select *`.

Comment: If I would need to insert them in a table.. what do I add to query?

Comment: For inserting, you should know the number of columns.

Comment: @Mahesh Not necessarily.  You can insert into a new table using `SELECT INTO`. (although I do agree with your statement with regards to existing tables)